Flutter: SharedPreferences wrapper class Testing is returning null
Im having an issue were I have the following Preferences.dart
preferences.dart
/// Wrapper class for the shared preferences.
class Preferences {
  Preferences({required SharedPreferences sharedPreferences})
      : _sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
  final SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;

  /// Writes the [value] to the shared preferences.
  Future<bool> write({required String key, required String value}) =>
      _sharedPreferences.setString(key, value);

  /// Writes the list of [values] to the shared preferences.
  Future<bool> writeList({required String key, required List<String> values}) =>
      _sharedPreferences.setStringList(key, values);

  /// Reads the value from the shared preferences.
  String? read({required String key}) => _sharedPreferences.getString(key);

  /// Reads the list of values from the shared preferences.
  List<String>? readList({required String key}) =>
      _sharedPreferences.getStringList(key);

  /// Clears the shared preferences.
  Future<bool> clearAll() => _sharedPreferences.clear();

  /// Clears the shared preferences for the given [key].
  Future<bool> clear({required String key}) => _sharedPreferences.remove(key);
}

while trying to create the respective test class, im always receiving the following error:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<bool>' test/mocks/mocks.dart 8:7                            MockPreferences.write test/domain/preferences/preferences_test.dart 19:26  main.<fn>
Currently this is the test class that im using:
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:garrapata_app/domain/preferences/preferences.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import '../../mocks/mocks.dart';

void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  late Preferences mockPreferences;

  setUpAll(() async {
    SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({'demo': 'demo'});
    mockPreferences = MockPreferences();
  });

  test('demo', () {
    when(mockPreferences.write(key: 'demo', value: 'demo')).thenAnswer((_) async => true);
    expect(mockPreferences.write(key: 'demo', value: 'demo'), completion(true));
  });
}

Im not sure the reason why is keep getting null, the initialization of the mock values was settled and the assignation was done.

You didn't wait to get the completed result from SharedPreferences set or remove method
  Future<bool> write({required String key, required String value}) =>
      _sharedPreferences.setString(key, value);

Fix Example
  Future<bool> write({required String key, required String value}) =>
     await _sharedPreferences.setString(key, value);

await for the set method, any SharedPreferences set method requires to be waited for.
here's the Shared Preferences helper:
class Preferences {
  Preferences({required SharedPreferences sharedPreferences})
      : _sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
  final SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;

  /// Writes the [value] to the shared preferences.
  Future<bool> write({required String key, required String value}) async=>
     await _sharedPreferences.setString(key, value);

  /// Writes the list of [values] to the shared preferences.
  Future<bool> writeList({required String key, required List<String> values})async =>
     await _sharedPreferences.setStringList(key, values);

  /// Reads the value from the shared preferences.
  String? read({required String key}) => _sharedPreferences.getString(key);

  /// Reads the list of values from the shared preferences.
  List<String>? readList({required String key}) =>
      _sharedPreferences.getStringList(key);

  /// Clears the shared preferences.
  Future<bool> clearAll() async=> await _sharedPreferences.clear();

  /// Clears the shared preferences for the given [key].
  Future<bool> clear({required String key})async => await _sharedPreferences.remove(key);
}

Hope it helps you.
